# how to put particular marker in center from list of markers

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

i have ListView which showing the number of locations, when i click on any location the map is showing with marker of all the list of location but i want to show the selected location's marker in center and others are there area.

How to show the selected location in center and others are as it is

Answer (score 0):

gMap is the object of `GoogleMap`

```
gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker) {
                    marker.showInfoWindow();

                    LatLng currentPoint = new LatLng(26.5886, 72.982);// pass here your selected marker coordinate(Latitude & Longitude) like lat
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPoint, 7);// set here your zoom level
                    gMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

for e.g.

```
gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker marker) {
                    marker.showInfoWindow();

                    YourModel myMarker = mMarkersHashMap.get(marker);// it is your model 
                    LatLng currentPoint = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(myMarker.getLat()), Double.valueOf(myMarker.getLon()));
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentPoint, 7);
                    gMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```